# facing connection leak issues with c3p0

Tags: java, mysql-connector, c3p0

I am using apache tomcat 7.0.52 with c3p0-0.9.1.jar.

These are connection pool parameters

```
<Resource auth="Container" factory="org.apache.naming.factory.BeanFactory" 
        name="jdbc/hhmefep"
        driverClass="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" connectionTesterClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.integration.c3p0.MysqlConnectionTester"
        preferredTestQuery="/* ping */" idleConnectionTestPeriod="60"
        jdbcUrl="jdbc:mysql:loadbalance://dba.clean,dbb.clean/hhmefep?autoReconnectForPools=true&amp;maxReconnects=1&amp;initialTimeout=1&amp;retriesAllDown=2&amp;queriesBeforeRetryMaster=50&amp;secondsBeforeRetryMaster=5&amp;failOverReadOnly=false&amp;allowMasterDownConnections=true&amp;loadBalanceBlacklistTimeout=30000&amp;loadBalanceExceptionChecker=com.mi.utility.NdbLoadBalanceExceptionChecker&amp;loadBalanceSQLExceptionSubclassFailover=java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException&amp;loadBalancePingTimeout=500&amp;loadBalanceSQLStateFailover=08,1205&amp;connectTimeout=100"
        user="hhmefep" password="hhmefep"
        initialPoolSize="25" minPoolSize="25" maxPoolSize="25" maxStatements="100"
        unreturnedConnectionTimeout="60" debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces="true"
        maxIdleTime="600" numHelperThreads="20" maxAdministrativeTaskTime="5"
        testConnectionOnCheckout="true" testConnectionOnCheckin="true"
        acquireRetryAttempts="3" acquireRetryDelay="500" type="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" />

<Resource auth="Container" factory="org.apache.naming.factory.BeanFactory" 
        name="jdbc/hhmebep"
        driverClass="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" connectionTesterClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.integration.c3p0.MysqlConnectionTester"
        preferredTestQuery="/* ping */" idleConnectionTestPeriod="60"
        jdbcUrl="jdbc:mysql:loadbalance://dba.clean,dbb.clean/hhmebep?autoReconnectForPools=true&amp;maxReconnects=1&amp;initialTimeout=1&amp;retriesAllDown=2&amp;queriesBeforeRetryMaster=50&amp;secondsBeforeRetryMaster=5&amp;failOverReadOnly=false&amp;allowMasterDownConnections=true&amp;loadBalanceBlacklistTimeout=30000&amp;loadBalanceExceptionChecker=com.mi.utility.NdbLoadBalanceExceptionChecker&amp;loadBalanceSQLExceptionSubclassFailover=java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException&amp;loadBalancePingTimeout=500&amp;loadBalanceSQLStateFailover=08,1205&amp;connectTimeout=100"
        user="hhmebep" password="hhmebep"
        initialPoolSize="15" minPoolSize="15" maxPoolSize="15" maxStatements="100"
        unreturnedConnectionTimeout="60" debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces="true"
        maxIdleTime="600" numHelperThreads="20" maxAdministrativeTaskTime="5"
        testConnectionOnCheckout="true" testConnectionOnCheckin="true"
        acquireRetryAttempts="3" acquireRetryDelay="500" type="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" />

<Resource auth="Container" factory="org.apache.naming.factory.BeanFactory" 
        name="jdbc/hhmelmtacc"
        driverClass="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" connectionTesterClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.integration.c3p0.MysqlConnectionTester"
        preferredTestQuery="/* ping */" idleConnectionTestPeriod="60"
        jdbcUrl="jdbc:mysql:loadbalance://dba.clean,dbb.clean/hhmelmtacc?autoReconnectForPools=true&amp;maxReconnects=1&amp;initialTimeout=1&amp;retriesAllDown=2&amp;queriesBeforeRetryMaster=50&amp;secondsBeforeRetryMaster=5&amp;failOverReadOnly=false&amp;allowMasterDownConnections=true&amp;loadBalanceBlacklistTimeout=30000&amp;loadBalanceExceptionChecker=com.mi.utility.NdbLoadBalanceExceptionChecker&amp;loadBalanceSQLExceptionSubclassFailover=java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException&amp;loadBalancePingTimeout=500&amp;loadBalanceSQLStateFailover=08,1205&amp;connectTimeout=100"
        user="hhmelmtacc" password="hhmelmtacc"
        initialPoolSize="10" minPoolSize="10" maxPoolSize="10" maxStatements="100"
        unreturnedConnectionTimeout="60" debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces="true"
        maxIdleTime="600" numHelperThreads="20" maxAdministrativeTaskTime="5"
        testConnectionOnCheckout="true" testConnectionOnCheckin="true"
        acquireRetryAttempts="3" acquireRetryDelay="500" type="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" />
```

I am getting exception as given below:

```
Jul 14, 2014 1:32:20 PM com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection handleThrowable
WARNING: [c3p0] A PooledConnection that has already signalled a Connection error is still in use!
Jul 14, 2014 1:32:20 PM com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection handleThrowable
WARNING: [c3p0] Another error has occurred [ com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after connection closed.  Connection explicitly closed. ] which will not be reported to listeners!
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after connection closed.  Connection explicitly closed.
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor106.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:409)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:384)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1013)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:987)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:973)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:918)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.LoadBalancingConnectionProxy.invoke(LoadBalancingConnectionProxy.java:624)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.LoadBalancingConnectionProxy.invoke(LoadBalancingConnectionProxy.java:549)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy60.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor51.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$1StmtAcquireTask.run(GooGooStatementCache.java:525)
        at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:547)

Jul 14, 2014 1:32:20 PM com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection handleThrowable
WARNING: [c3p0] A PooledConnection that has already signalled a Connection error is still in use!
Jul 14, 2014 1:32:20 PM com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection handleThrowable
WARNING: [c3p0] Another error has occurred [ com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after connection closed.  Connection explicitly closed. ] which will not be reported to listeners!
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after connection closed.  Connection explicitly closed.
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor106.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:409)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:384)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1013)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:987)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:973)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:918)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.LoadBalancingConnectionProxy.invoke(LoadBalancingConnectionProxy.java:624)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.LoadBalancingConnectionProxy.invoke(LoadBalancingConnectionProxy.java:549)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy60.getAutoCommit(Unknown Source)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyConnection.getAutoCommit(NewProxyConnection.java:985)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.isAutoCommit(ConnectionManager.java:212)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.JDBCContext.afterNontransactionalQuery(JDBCContext.java:287)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.afterOperation(SessionImpl.java:595)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1724)
        at org.hibernate.impl.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:347)
        at com.mii.core.gateway.MIMetadataService.getUserById(MIMetadataService.java:1278)
        at com.mii.core.sec.MIUserDetailService.loadUserByUsername(MIUserDetailService.java:51)
        at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:101)
        at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.java:132)
        at com.mii.core.sec.MIIAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(MIIAuthenticationProvider.java:12)
        at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:156)
        at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:177)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:94)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:211)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at com.mii.core.sec.MIIUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(MIIUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:38)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:315)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)

org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not inspect JDBC autocommit mode
        at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:99)
        at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
        at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:52)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.JDBCContext.afterNontransactionalQuery(JDBCContext.java:296)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.afterOperation(SessionImpl.java:595)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1724)
        at org.hibernate.impl.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:347)
        at com.mii.core.gateway.MIMetadataService.getUserById(MIMetadataService.java:1278)
        at com.mii.core.sec.MIUserDetailService.loadUserByUsername(MIUserDetailService.java:51)
        at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:101)
        at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.java:132)
        at com.mii.core.sec.MIIAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(MIIAuthenticationProvider.java:12)
        at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:156)
        at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:177)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:94)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:211)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at com.mii.core.sec.MIIUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(MIIUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:38)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:315)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after connection closed.  Connection explicitly closed.
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor106.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:409)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:384)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1013)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:987)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:973)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:918)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.LoadBalancingConnectionProxy.invoke(LoadBalancingConnectionProxy.java:624)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.LoadBalancingConnectionProxy.invoke(LoadBalancingConnectionProxy.java:549)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy60.getAutoCommit(Unknown Source)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyConnection.getAutoCommit(NewProxyConnection.java:985)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.isAutoCommit(ConnectionManager.java:212)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.JDBCContext.afterNontransactionalQuery(JDBCContext.java:287)
        ... 42 more
Jul 14, 2014 1:32:20 PM com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection handleThrowable
WARNING: [c3p0] A PooledConnection that has already signalled a Connection error is still in use!
Jul 14, 2014 1:32:20 PM com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection handleThrowable
WARNING: [c3p0] Another error has occurred [ com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after connection closed.  Connection explicitly closed. ] which will not be reported to listeners!
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after connection closed.  Connection explicitly closed.
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor106.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:409)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:384)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1013)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:987)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:973)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:918)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.LoadBalancingConnectionProxy.invoke(LoadBalancingConnectionProxy.java:624)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.LoadBalancingConnectionProxy.invoke(LoadBalancingConnectionProxy.java:549)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy60.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor51.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$1StmtAcquireTask.run(GooGooStatementCache.java:525)
        at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:547)

org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException: User 'ADMIN' not found
        at com.mii.core.sec.MIUserDetailService.loadUserByUsername(MIUserDetailService.java:57)
        at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:101)
        at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.java:132)
        at com.mii.core.sec.MIIAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(MIIAuthenticationProvider.java:12)
        at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:156)
        at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:177)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:94)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:211)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at com.mii.core.sec.MIIUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(MIIUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:38)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:315)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

There are majority chances that I have either missed important configuration or given improper values to tune c3p0.

**Edit:** I am using ndbcluster 7.3.5 and when I am executing redundancy tests which includes interface, link, power up/down and manual system restart scenarios. At this time I am facing this issue.

Can you help me on this ?

Comment: Are you calling `close` on the connections you are given by the pool when you are finished with them. That is the mechanism you use with connection pools to tell them the connection can be re-used. You must not re-use the closed connection - you must get a new one for any subsequent queries.

Comment: seconding old curmudgeon here... it looks like you are trying to work with a c3p0 Connection that your code has already called close() upon. It is now an empty proxy, the true Connection has fled back into the pool.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look into the code. I have updated the question with more details. @SteveWaldman can you take a look and guide me further ?